# Full ubuntu-9.10 from minimal cd?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, installation

I'm in the process of reinstalling a (very) old machine that doesn't have a DVD drive (CD only) and I'm running into problems getting the over-sized ubuntu image to fit on a CD. Unfortunately the motherboard doesn't support boot from USB, so that isn't an option.

Is it possible to get a full ubuntu 9.10 distro up and running from the minimal CD? can anyone offer advice or suggestions on how to do this?

**Update**

I understand *what* the minimal CD and *where* I get it, but once I've burnt it, is there any easy way to get back to an equivalent of the standard ubuntu iso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the minimal disk will download all the packages needed off the net as necessary. Once thats's done, pick one of the meta packages (ubuntu-desktop , kubuntu-desktop etc) and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Minimal Distribution of Ubuntu from [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this link from the Ubuntu Forums useful: [How to Acheive "Ubuntu minimal"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1155961)

-El Di Pablo